How do I add a button to a menu in another (custom) extension?
I've got a few VSIX projects that depend on a parent VSIX. In that parent I have a menu and I want to be able to add buttons to that parent menu.
So this is the Parent VSCommandTable.vsct:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CommandTable xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005-10-18/CommandTable" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <Extern href="stdidcmd.h"/>
  <Extern href="vsshlids.h"/>
  <Include href="KnownImageIds.vsct"/>
  <Include href="VSGlobals.vsct"/>

  <Commands package="ParentPackage">
    <Groups>     
      <Group guid="ParentPackage" id="ParentGroup" priority="0x0600">
        <Parent guid="ParentPackage" id="ParentMenu"/>
      </Group>
    </Groups>

    <Menus>     
      <Menu guid="ParentPackage" id="ParentMenu" priority="0x100" type="Menu">
        <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDG_VS_MM_TOOLSADDINS" />
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>Parent</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Menu>
    </Menus>
    
    <Buttons>
      <Button guid="ParentPackage" id="OptionsCommand" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
        <Parent guid="ParentPackage" id="ParentGroup" />
        <Icon guid="ImageCatalogGuid" id="Settings" />
        <CommandFlag>IconIsMoniker</CommandFlag>
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>Options</ButtonText>
          <LocCanonicalName>.ParentPackage.OptionsCommand</LocCanonicalName>
        </Strings>
      </Button>      
    </Buttons>
  </Commands>

  <Symbols>
    <GuidSymbol name="ParentPackage" value="{fff82d40-a222-33cd-9145-792a25276511}">
      <IDSymbol name="ParentGroup" value="0x0011" />
      <IDSymbol name="ParentMenu" value="0x0012" />
      <IDSymbol name="OptionsCommand" value="0x0033" />
    </GuidSymbol>
  </Symbols>
</CommandTable>

And this is the Child VSCommandTable.vsct:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CommandTable xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005-10-18/CommandTable" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <Extern href="stdidcmd.h"/>
    <Extern href="vsshlids.h"/>
    <Include href="KnownImageIds.vsct"/>
    <Include href="VSGlobals.vsct"/>

    <Commands package="ChildPackage">
        <Groups>
            <Group guid="ChildPackage" id="DummyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
                <Parent guid="VSMainMenu" id="Tools"/>
            </Group>
        </Groups>

        <Buttons>
            <Button guid="ChildPackage" id="DummyCommand" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
                <Parent guid="ParentPackage" id="ParentGroup" />
                <Icon guid="ImageCatalogGuid" id="StatusInformation" />
                <CommandFlag>IconIsMoniker</CommandFlag>
                <Strings>
                    <ButtonText>Dummy Command</ButtonText>
                    <LocCanonicalName>.ChildPackage.DummyCommand</LocCanonicalName>
                </Strings>
            </Button>
        </Buttons>
    </Commands>

    <Symbols>
        <GuidSymbol name="ChildPackage" value="{FFF82D40-A852-43CD-9145-792A25276574}">
            <IDSymbol name="DummyMenuGroup" value="0x0001" />
            <IDSymbol name="DummyCommand" value="0x0100" />
        </GuidSymbol>
    </Symbols>
</CommandTable>

And obviously, this line; <Parent guid="ParentPackage" id="ParentGroup" /> does not compile because the ParentPackage guid and  id are unknown. So I added an Include to the other vsct file and that seemed to solve that problem..
<Include href="..\ParentProject\VSCommandTable.vsct" />

However, that introduced this monstrosity;

I get that I might get a duplicate Options, because that I import the file, but I'm baffled it produces this...? Does anybody have an answer what I do wrong?

I think you should be able to copy/paste the appropriate  section from your ParentProject's .vsct into the child one and then that'll be known by the compiler as well. You can probably also break that  section out to a separate file and include it in both.

Okay, that was one thing I hadn't tried, but adding the <GuidSymbol> from the parent to the child class worked like a charm! Thanks!
If I put it in a separate file, what extension should I give it, or doesn't that matter?

The symbol is used just by the vsct compiler as best I know, just think of it like a #define in a header file.

Jason Malinowski's comment is the correct answer. Thanks Jason!
The child vsct is looking like this now and that works like a charm. I'm going to put the symbols in separate files so I don't have to maintain the parents symbols in multiple places, but that should be it!
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CommandTable xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005-10-18/CommandTable" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <Extern href="stdidcmd.h"/>
    <Extern href="vsshlids.h"/>
    <Include href="KnownImageIds.vsct"/>
    <Include href="VSGlobals.vsct"/>

    <Commands package="ChildPackage">
        <Groups>
            <Group guid="ChildPackage" id="DummyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
                <Parent guid="VSMainMenu" id="Tools"/>
            </Group>
        </Groups>

        <Buttons>
            <Button guid="ChildPackage" id="DummyCommand" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
                <Parent guid="ParentPackage" id="ParentGroup" />
                <Icon guid="ImageCatalogGuid" id="StatusInformation" />
                <CommandFlag>IconIsMoniker</CommandFlag>
                <Strings>
                    <ButtonText>Dummy Command</ButtonText>
                    <LocCanonicalName>.ChildPackage.DummyCommand</LocCanonicalName>
                </Strings>
            </Button>
        </Buttons>
    </Commands>

    <Symbols>
        <GuidSymbol name="ParentPackage" value="{fff82d40-a222-33cd-9145-792a25276511}">
          <IDSymbol name="ParentGroup" value="0x0011" />
          <IDSymbol name="ParentMenu" value="0x0012" />
          <IDSymbol name="OptionsCommand" value="0x0033" />
        </GuidSymbol>
        <GuidSymbol name="ChildPackage" value="{FFF82D40-A852-43CD-9145-792A25276574}">
            <IDSymbol name="DummyMenuGroup" value="0x0001" />
            <IDSymbol name="DummyCommand" value="0x0100" />
        </GuidSymbol>
    </Symbols>
</CommandTable>

